# can I use "although in most of .." or should I omit the in?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

i the below use correct ?

> 1. We can see that **although in most of** the times telling the truth is the best choice it's not always so.

or should i say

> 2. we can see that **although most of** the times telling the truth is the best choice it's not always so."

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to phrase it is **[most of the time](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/most%20of%20the%20time)**: "We can see that although **most of the time** telling the truth is the best choice it's not always so."  Using *in* is definitely incorrect.

Comment: Should i also omit the s in "times"

Comment: Yes, it's "most of the time", not "times".

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is correct. No need for "in" before "most of the time".

"We can see that although most of the time telling the truth is the best choice it's not always so."